# robot-framework prints logs in console with blank lines & seperators

Tags: python, robotframework

Robot framework is prefixed with "line" literal & every line is seperated by a lot of equal symbols. And each line is printed with a blank space in between?

How to configure robot to pretty print the logs?

Console log excerpt:
    line ==============================================================================

```
line Create Tenant                                                         | FAIL |

line UnboundLocalError: local variable 'robotResponse' referenced before assignment

line ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

line tc CreateTenant & tc CreateWLAN.tc CreateTenant                       | FAIL |

line 1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
```

==============================================================================

Answer (score 1):

There's not much you can do. There is a fairly old feature request asking for a way to custom it. Your only other option is to redirect all output to /dev/null and then create a listener that prints any information you want.

https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/317